# await client.queryasync taking too long

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, salesforce, salesforce-communities

Hi I am using Developer force of Sales force to get the account details, i am not getting any response while executing
await, the response is taking too long, any alternative for this await in sales force

var results = await client.QueryAsync(constants.AccountsQuery);

Comment: What query are you running? How many Accounts are in the Salesforce org and how many match the query filters? Queries that are poorly optimized or attempt to return too much data can certainly time out.

Comment: Most probably you have gotten an exception after running this code. Try to wrap your code in a try-catch block to see what happens after calling this method.

Comment: just  "SELECT top 1 Name,Accountnumber,OwnerID,Site,AccountSource,Active__c,AnnualRevenue," +
                     "CleanStatus,CreatedById, Description,NumberofEmployees,Fax,Industry,Phone,Rating," +
                        "Type,Website,YearStarted FROM Account"

Comment: @salahAkbari try catch already there in the block

Comment: Use a good profiler to find where exactly the time is being spent.

Comment: @Zer0 this is running fine in Console application, in MVC 5 Controller, its giving Unlimited TImeout Issue

Comment: Sounds like a possible deadlock maybe?  Can you share more code or something that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> this is running fine in Console application, in MVC 5 Controller, its giving Unlimited TImeout Issue

Most likely, this means that further up your call stack, some code is calling an asynchronous and then blocking on the task it returns (using `.Result`, `.Wait()`, or `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`). The solution is: [don't block on asynchronous code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Instead of blocking, use [`async` all the way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming). Change the `Result`/`Wait` to use `await` instead, and the compiler will guide you from there.